# MongoDB restore warning

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-a-mongodb-database-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to backup and restore a single MongoDB database.

The backup command -

```
sudo mongodump --db newdb --out /var/backups/mongobackups/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

The restore command -

```
sudo mongorestore --db newdb --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16/newdb/
```

Although it works perfectly, MongoDB gives me this warning while restoring the data -

> the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead

Can someone explain how to remove this warning?

I'm using MongoDB 3.4.1 version.

Answer (score 33):

`--nsInclude` is new in mongo 3.4.

Instead of older options where `db_name` and `collection_name` are given in command line as

```
mongorestore --db db_name --collection collection_name
```

namespaces are to be used

```
mongorestore --nsInclude db_name.collection_name
```

Similarly

```
mongorestore --db newdb --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16/newdb/
```

becomes

```
mongorestore --nsInclude 'newdb.*' --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16/
```

Comment: I wan't to know why its giving me an error even though I'm restoring from a BSON file.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and finally I noticed that I had missed the actual backup folder URL. My backup database folder is in a subfolder.

I was trying for

```
sudo mongorestore -d database 'Database-13-03-23'
```

But it should be

```
sudo mongorestore -d database 'Database-13-03-23/13-03-23/database'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I also had a typo in my restore folder name.  The inaccurate error you get when you do this is frustratingly poor.

Answer (score 0):

You could **remove --db** and the error will goes away:

```
mongorestore  newdb  --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16/
```

In my case, I didn't need any flag to set the db name.

Comment: Then how does mongorestore know the name of the DB to restore into?  Why does the command contradict its own self?  When I run it with "--help", it prints

```Usage:
  mongorestore <options> <connection-string> <directory or file to restore>
...
```

Furthermore, that same help command lists 2 separate "namespace options" sections; the first one shows the "-d" and "-c" options; the second one shows all the switches starting with "ns*".  The whole thing is messed up.  Whoever created these command-line tools needs to be tarred, feathered, and summarily executed.

Answer (score -12):

just execute command like this:

```
sudo mongorestore /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16
```